# Join in Hive with Concatenated Columns

Tags: sql, join, hive, concatenation

I have 2 tables I need to join in Hive on a key that is created by concatenating 2 columns in each table (the ID and State columns below). Below is an example of my data:

Table 1:

```
ID State Year Name
1234 VA 2019 Liz
2345 MI 2018 Pat
5656 OH 2018 Meg
1562 MI 2019 John
1234 OH 2018 Sam
2345 PA 2019 George
```

Table 2:

```
ID State Salary Age
1562 MI 32 37
2345 PA 60 70
5616 MI 52 82
1234 VA 50 35
2345 MI 60 45
5656 OH 45 40
1234 OH 52 52
```

I need perform a left join using a key that is created by concatenating the "ID" and "State" columns. The output should be as follows:

```
ID State Year Name Salary Age
1234 VA 2019 Liz 50 35
2345 MI 2018 Pat 60 45
5656 OH 2018 Meg 45 40
1562 MI 2019 John 32 37
1234 OH 2018 Sam 52 50
2345 PA 2019 George 60 70
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use left join as below:

```
Select t1.ID, t1.[state], t1.[year], t1.[name], t2.salary, t2.age
    from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.[state] = t2.[state]
```

Comment: Thank you! Very easy, can't believe I didn't think of that. I do have another question. In the same query, I need to transpose table 2 to get it into this form. Right now, I have multiple queries to do this, but want to consolidate. Initially, Table 2 is in long form with the following columns: ID State Metric Value
1234 VA year 2019
1234 VA name Liz
1234 VA Salary 50
1234 VA Age 35

I would like it to look like listed in my first post and then join the wide versions of both tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate anything.  Just use two keys for the `join`:

```
select . . .   -- list the columns you want here
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.state = t2.state;
```